# How to remove foreign key without deleting the whole entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, jhipster

I am new to Spring boot and I want to be able to delete the value of a forgein key if its entity is removed without deleting the whole entity linked to it; I explain in my case a single person who has an Account can be at the same time an Author and a Player, so if I delete an author I want to delete its refrence in Account table without deleting the whole account because this account can still point on player. I searched on the internet I found cascadetype but it will delete the whole account!

Thank you in advance!
here is my entities

```
@Table(name = "account")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Account implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Author")
    private Author author;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Player")
    private Player player;

    //attributs, getters & setters
}

@Table(name = "player")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Player implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

   //attributs, getters & setters
}


//ma.myapp.usersgestion.domain.Author

@Table(name = "author")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Author implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "player", "author"}, allowSetters = true)
    private Set<Account> accounts = new HashSet<>();

   //attributs, getters & setters
}
```

UPDATE

Im using jhipster (spring boot with React) and h2 database (with disk-based persistence)

```
//AuthorResource.java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@Transactional
public class AuthorResource {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthorResource.class);

    private static final String ENTITY_NAME = "author";

    @Value("${jhipster.clientApp.name}")
    private String applicationName;

    private final AuthorRepository authorRepository;

    public AuthorResource(AuthorRepository authorRepository) {
        this.authorRepository = authorRepository;
    }
/**
     * {@code DELETE  /authors/:id} : delete the "id" author.
     *
     * @param id the id of the author to delete.
     * @return the {@link ResponseEntity} with status {@code 204 (NO_CONTENT)}.
     */
    @DeleteMapping("/authors/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteAuthor(@PathVariable Long id) {
        log.debug("REST request to delete Author : {}", id);
        authorRepository.deleteById(id);
        return ResponseEntity
            .noContent()
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityDeletionAlert(applicationName, true, ENTITY_NAME, id.toString()))
            .build();
    }
   
//...
}

//AuthorRepository

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Repository
public interface AuthorRepository extends JpaRepository<Author, Long> {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your entity class author add the following:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "author", cascade = { CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST })
private Set<Account> accounts;
```

I've omitted the cascadetype `CascadeType.REMOVE` from the list. This will prevent `Account` from also being deleted when the related `Author` entity is deleted.

EDIT:

If the above solution somehow doesn't work then you can also try adding `@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.NO_ACTION)` above the `accounts` field.

`@OnDelete` is a `hibernate` specific annotation.

EDIT 2:

If none of the solutions provided above work then you can also consider making a `javax.persistence.@PreRemove` annotated method that manually sets the `author` field for each related `Account` to null. You place this method inside the `Author` class. A method that is annotated with `@PreRemove` will always run before the entity is deleted. So for `Author` you could use the following method to set all author_id fields to null.

```
@PreRemove
public void deleteAuthor(){
   this.getAccounts().forEach(account -> account.setAuthor(null));
}
```

Comment: Thank you first for your help. I tried both but unfortunately It didn't work my h2 database still have the refrence of the deleted entity

Comment: What do you mean with `my h2 database still have the refrence of the deleted entity`?

Comment: Im using Jhipster with h2 database. So when I delete an author who was linked to an account X, its id stills in  account X. and when I want to list all accounts jhispter gives error `.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find ma.myapp.usersgestion.domain.Author with id 9651; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find ma.myapp.usersgestion.domain.Author with id 9651] ` so when I go to h2 db and i remove the value of author_id in that account X. the error disappears

Comment: @Hakimam could you show the code of `ma.myapp.usersgestion.domain.Author` too then? Please also post  the code of the delete method as well.

Comment: Okey I add it above in code section.. since I am using JHipster those classes are generated automatically.

Comment: @Hakimam, maybe the error is caused because the cached version of  `Account` isn't properly updated when you delete an `Author` from the database. Remove the annotation `@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)` from `Account` and try again. When `Account` objects are no longer cached they will always be retrieved from the database, which means you'll always get the up to date versions of the `Accounts`

Comment: @Hakim, nevermind my last comment, i didn't read the part where you mention that removing the value of author_id makes the error disappear. I really don't know what is causing the value of `author_id` to remain in `Account` after the `Author` is deleted. However you can still manually set the `author_id` field for each `Account` to `null` using a `@PreRemove` annotated method that you define in the `Author` class. I'll update my answer to give you an example.

Comment: Please where should I call method `deleteAuthor` can I do it inside this method in AuthorResource.java?`@DeleteMapping("/authors/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteAuthor(@PathVariable Long id) {...authorRepository.deleteById(id);}`

Comment: @Hakimam you don't have to call it. The annotation `@PreRemove` will cause the method to be automatically called the moment `deleteById(authorId)` is called. When that happens Spring/Hibernate will first retrieve the Author entity from the database. It will then check for any methods inside `Author` that are annotated with `@PreRemove`. If it has found such a method it will execute the method first before deleting the `Author` instance. This goes completely automatic. You can test this by also adding a log command inside the delete method. `System.out.println("Delete method executing");`

Comment: My pleasure. @Hakimam